# selectonemenu with ace datatable - values lost

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, icefaces, icefaces-3

Maybe someone could help me?

I have an ace:datatable, where one column uses a "selectonemenu" in the inline editing mode.

```
<ace:column id="bundesland" headerText="Bundesland">
    <ace:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">

            <h:outputText id="bundeslandCell1" value="Baden-Württemberg" rendered="#{current.bundesland == 1}"/>  
            <h:outputText id="bundeslandCell2" value="Bayern" rendered="#{current.bundesland == 2}"/>  
            <h:outputText id="bundeslandCell3" value="Hamburg" rendered="#{current.bundesland == 3}"/>  
            <h:outputText id="bundeslandCell4" value="Nordrhein-Westfalen" rendered="#{current.bundesland == 4}"/>  
            <h:outputText id="bundeslandCell5" value="Sachsen" rendered="#{current.bundesland == 5}"/>

        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">

            <h:selectOneMenu id="bundeslandInput" value="#{current.bundesland}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Baden-Württemberg" itemValue="1" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bayern" itemValue="2" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hamburg" itemValue="3" />    
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Nordrhein-Westfalen" itemValue="4" />    
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sachsen" itemValue="5" />                                  
            </h:selectOneMenu>

        </f:facet>
    </ace:cellEditor>   
</ace:column>
```

The datatable is assigned to a List of a bean, which refers to other beans...

Problem is that the field "bundesland" looses data, if I submit the form of the datatable.

For example:

- add new row too the datatable using action listener
- inline edit the non persistent new row
- perform save

Everything fine!

Now I want to insert a new row. I do the same steps again. The next Time, performing the "save", clicking on the Command Button cleared the column "bundesland" in the whole datatable (with persist).

Problem is not the action behind the Command Button. The columns will be cleared, also if the CommandButton has no actionListener..

So far...

Why does Icefaces clear the column "bundesland" in every row, only if i use the selectonemenu?

Using  in the "Inline Editing"-Mode is still no Problem.

Thanks for help!